# Title post on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Sometimes, I just don't know what the title should be for a given question/problem on Stack Overflow, though I can detail the question/problem...

What should I do in such case as I really don't want to be blocked again?

Comment: Think about the question - what makes it different from other questions. Make that your title.

Comment: For an example, look at the title of your question here and the title of your duplicate. Which one is more descriptive? Ask yourself "What is it I want to know?", or in case of a bug/problem "What is the problem I'm experiencing". If you can answer those questions and then narrow them down to a single short sentence, you're getting close to a decent title.

Comment: Also, try reading your title out loud, or reading it to a friend or colleague. Does it make sense to anyone? If not, then that's a bad title.